# Simulate mysql compress function using c#

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, entity-framework, compression

I'd like to insert some byte data into a mysql blob column.
The data is large so I want to store it in a compressed way.

I'm using Entity Framework 3.5SP1 to insert the data into the mysql database using the latest mysql .net connector. Is there a way to either use the entitiy framework to insert a blob into the mysql database (like `insert into testtable (blobcolumn) values (compress('aaa'))`) or to emulate the `compress` function of mysql in c# and then insert the result in the database?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Specify a ['UseCompression'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-connection-options.html) option in the connection string to enable compression of packets.

Comment: Isn't this just about the traffic, not storage?

Comment: It is about the traffic. Some storage engines provide this feature as well (ROW_FORMAT table option), e.g. INNODB compression - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb-plugin/1.0/en/innodb-compression.html

Comment: I don't want to compress the whole table but instead write one column in mysql compressed format. Practically what this means is that I want to insert a dataset using .net and select the dateset using the uncompress function of mysql.

Comment: About the emulation in c#: I'm not sure if it is possible. From the COMPRESS function doc: 'This function requires MySQL to have been compiled with a compression library such as zlib.' So, we do not know exact compression mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Please find below my implementation using [Ionic zip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) .
Hope that helps!

`using System;
using System.IO;
using Ionic.Zlib;
using System.Text;

namespace Qobuz
{
    public static class MySqlCompressHelper
    {
        public static byte[] MySqlCompress(this string str, CompressionLevel level = CompressionLevel.BestCompression)
        {
            return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str).MySqlCompress(level);
        }

        public static byte[] MySqlCompress(this byte[] buffer, CompressionLevel level = CompressionLevel.BestCompression)
        {
            using (var output = new MemoryStream())
            {
                output.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)buffer.Length), 0, 4);
                using (var compressor = new ZlibStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress, level))
                {
                    compressor.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }

                return output.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public static string MySqlUncompressString(this byte[] buffer)
        {
            return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.MySqlUncompressBuffer());
        }

        public static byte[] MySqlUncompressBuffer(this byte[] buffer)
        {
            using (var output = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var decompressor = new ZlibStream(output, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    decompressor.Write(buffer, 4, buffer.Length - 4);
                }

                return output.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}`